# linux headers not found

Tags: 12.04, installation, drivers, nvidia, kernel

I upgraded to ubuntu 12.04 and the x server is not running anymore.

It turned out to be the nvidia driver, so I installed nvidia-current.

Doing this I got an error message telling me that linux sources are not available.

`uname -r` reports: `2.6.32-34-generic-pae`

So I tried: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.32.34-generic-pae`

But this package does not exist (anymore?)

Can anybody help me to get the required sources?

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading the relevant .deb file from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/linux-headers-2.6.32-34-generic-pae/2.6.32-34.77 and https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/i386/linux-headers-2.6.32-34/2.6.32-34.77:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/79829520/linux-headers-2.6.32-34-generic-pae_2.6.32-34.77_i386.deb
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/79829514/linux-headers-2.6.32-34_2.6.32-34.77_all.deb
```

And then install using:

```
sudo dpkg --install linux-headers-2.6.32-34-generic-pae_2.6.32-34.77_i386.deb linux-headers-2.6.32-34_2.6.32-34.77_all.deb
```

But unless there's a specific reason you're still using an old PAE kernel on 12.04, I think you would be better off using a kernel that is packaged in 12.04. The upgrade to 12.04 should have installed a newer kernel. Perhaps you need to update your grub default, or manually select a different kernel during boot?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-2.6.32-34
```

UPDATE:

Since you are running 12.04 (which I didn't noticed), these kernel headers are not available there. Precise got released with 3.2.14 (3.2.0-23.36).

Options:

- One of the options could be to download your kernel headers from 10.04 repo.
- Another option would be to update to latest kernel release for 12.04, but this might lead to other problems.

Comment: **That package is also not available in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.** (Furthermore, installing the kernel headers with `-generic-pae` at the end *is* the right way to do it, since that will automatically pull in everything you need for building modules against the `generic-pae` kernel. The problem here is that this kernel version is not provided with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS at all -- it's from a previous Ubuntu release.)

Answer (score 0):

For an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system, you are running quite an old kernel. The current generic PAE kernel version in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is `3.2.0-24-generic-pae`. The generic PAE kernel version that came with 12.04 LTS when it was first released was `3.2.0-23-generic-pae`. The kernel you're currently running is not provided in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS at all, which is why you cannot install headers for it. Your currently running kernel is from a previous Ubuntu release.

Unless you need to run such an old kernel, you should just use a newer kernel, and that will solve the problem. If you install the `linux-image-generic-pae` package, you'll get the latest stable kernel for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. If you install the `linux-headers-generic-pae` package, you'll get the latest headers. As you receive updates, both the kernel and headers will be updated for security and stability, and they will always correspond to each other (so the headers package will enable the compilation and installation of kernel modules for the kernel provided by the image package).

If you find that even with that installed, you are booting into the old kernel, then you may need to modify your GRUB2 configuration. If this happens, please provide details in your question.

If you need to run this very old kernel, please also provide details about what you need this for. For example, did you have to manually select this old kernel to boot successfully?

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I upgraded 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS and landed in this situation.
I have no idea why I am not running the new kernel.
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae tells me that the package is already the newest version. So I need something to force that kernel to be used during boot.
I'll dig into GRUB2 as you suggested. No idea yet what that is.
So if you can point me to a clue ...

Comment: @han What options do you have currently in your GRUB2 menu? (If the menu doesn't come up, press and hold the shift key while your machine boots.)

Comment: As I cannot spare the time to dig into this, I created a backup of the essential information on the disk. Format and reinstall 10.04 LTS. At a later time I will retry upgrading to 12.04. Probably more luck then. Thanks for being helpful!